# How to install a Steam demo you're developing?

Tags: steam, demo

When you own a game, Steam doesn't show you the demo to install it. But when you're developing the demo, you want to install it for testing.

Is it possible to get Steam to install my unreleased demo?

Comment: *Related player-oriented question: [How to force install a demo version of a game you already own on Steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/396339/62272).*

Answer (score 2):

The docs [say to create test accounts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/396408/62272) that don't own the game and grant them special keys. However, there is another way.

To run an unreleased demo you need to have a dev account with sufficient permissions. However, even with those permissions, the demo doesn't show up by default. You need to use something like Ashark's method.

Figure out your appid and use it below instead of DEMO_APPID. This will be **different** from your main game and you can find it on the [partner site](https://partner.steamgames.com/dashboard) next to the name of the demo.

Paste these instructions into Slack/Discord to share with your team (message yourself with them and test they work first!):

1. Click steam://open/console
2. That should open the Console tab in Steam. In there, run: `app_install DEMO_APPID`
3. You should now see the demo in Steam's Downloads. If you got a permissions error, you need our Steamworks admin to add permissions to your account.

*This answer condenses [Ashark's great answer for players](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/396408/62272) into something targeted to devs.*